# TypeScript: Why let print = console.log.bind(console) only works if there is a import before it?

Tags: typescript

I'm a bit puzzled that:

```
let print = console.log.bind(console)
```

Does not work (gives *"Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'print'"*), but this works perfectly:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs' //or even import { } from 'anything'
const print = console.log.bind(console)
```

More puzzling, using another name for the variable (like "printIt") works.

What's happening?

Comment: This is a bug in TypeScript. If you comment out line 19151 of `lib/lib.d.ts` in whatever TypeScript installation is running you'll see that it works. Try using any of the other variables declared in `lib.d.ts` (like `stop` on line 19160) and the same thing happens. No idea why it works after you declare an `import` though! I'd suggest reporting the issue to the official typescript repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top-level scope in a file is handled differently depending on the presence of top-level import or export statements. [This is not a bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18381#issuecomment-328584177):

> A file with one top-level import/export (e.g. test.ts in your example) is considered a module. modules have their own scope, and do not merge with global scope declarations.

So as soon as you have top-level import, `print` variable is now in its own scope and does not conflict with global `print` defined in [dom type declarations](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L15217) (in a browser environment, there is top-level global function named `print()` that [opens print current page dialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print)).

Comment: Ha! Mystery solved.  I was not aware of print in the browser. Also, I did not knew about import file handling, Things!